# Can this integral equality hold for any nonzero real $b$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Please may you kindly assist me on this integration exercise: Suppose for some fixed real $a, b$ with $a \neq 0$, we have:

$$\int_1^N f(x)\sin(a\log \sqrt x)x^b \mathrm{d}x = \int_1^N f(x)\sin(a\log \sqrt x)x^{-b} \mathrm{d}x $$

Where $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{2}\pi (n^{2}\pi -3/2x)e^{-n^{2}\pi x + 3/2x}$.

Can this equality be possible for any nonzero $b$ ?

Comment: I now feel that this question will perhaps be more  suitable for MO, can i cross-post it or delete from here and re-post on MO ?

Comment: Please may any moderator kindly delete this post from here, i'll be reposting it on MO in 10 minutes, where i feel is more suitable. Thank you.

Comment: Any clue why this should be true?

Comment: where exactly can i find this question a mo?

Comment: Does $3/2x$ represent $\frac{3}{2}x$ or $\frac{3}{2x}$?